# Evaluate SimpleXMLElement through PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

if I print out the following

```
$oXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($jobs);
```

I get data like so

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#359 (1) {
  ["Job"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#360 (10) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "J000001"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(13) "Internal Time"
      ["Description"]=>
      string(152) "Use this job to record your internal and non-billable time for activities such as annual leave, sick leave, professional development, staff meetings etc"
      ["Client"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#366 (2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(7) "8430219"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(11) "Fake Client"
      }
      ["ClientOrderNumber"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#367 (0) {
      }
      ["State"]=>
      string(7) "Planned"
      ["StartDate"]=>
      string(19) "2016-03-21T00:00:00"
      ["DueDate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-03-21T00:00:00"
      ["InternalID"]=>
      string(8) "11442733"
      ["Assigned"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#368 (1) {
        ["Staff"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#369 (2) {
          ["ID"]=>
          string(6) "344460"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(10) "Some Name"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#361 (10) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "J000002"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(26) "Setup and Conversion Steps"
      ["Description"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#368 (0) {
      }
      ["Client"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#367 (2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(7) "8550368"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(4) "Some Client"
      }
      ["ClientOrderNumber"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#366 (0) {
      }
      ["State"]=>
      string(7) "Planned"
      ["StartDate"]=>
      string(19) "2016-03-24T00:00:00"
      ["DueDate"]=>
      string(19) "2016-04-07T00:00:00"
      ["InternalID"]=>
      string(8) "11442734"
      ["Assigned"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#369 (1) {
        ["Staff"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#370 (2) {
          ["ID"]=>
          string(6) "344460"
          ["Name"]=>
          string(10) "John Doe"
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#362 (10) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "J000004"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(9) "retertret"
      ["Description"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#369 (0) {
      }
      ["Client"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#366 (2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(7) "8430219"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(11) "Fake Client"
      }
      ["ClientOrderNumber"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#367 (0) {
      }
      ["State"]=>
      string(7) "Planned"
      ["StartDate"]=>
      string(19) "2016-04-01T00:00:00"
      ["DueDate"]=>
      string(19) "2016-04-01T00:00:00"
      ["InternalID"]=>
      string(8) "11612898"
      ["Assigned"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#368 (0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So there are a lot of SimpleXMLElements, even inner ones.  What I am basically trying to do is create an array which has the ID as a key, and the Name as a value.
To do this, I am currently doing

```
$jobsArray = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($oXML->Jobs->Job as $job) {
    if($job->Client->Name->__toString() == $clientName->clientName) {
        $jobsArray[$i] = array(
            $job->ID->__toString() => $job->Name->__toString()
        );
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Now this appears to work, but only when I use __toString on everything.  For some reason this does not feel correct doing it this way.
Is there any way to improve the above or is there the need to use toString?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use (string)($job->ID) => (string)($job->Name). But when using XML/HTML objects, you often have to cast it...